# What is the meaning of "lug" in "lug nut"?

Tags: word-meaning, etymology

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lug_nut):

> A **lug nut** or wheel nut is a fastener, specifically a nut, used to secure a wheel on a vehicle. Typically, **lug nuts** are found on automobiles, trucks (lorries), and other large vehicles using rubber tires.

What is the meaning of "lug" here? [According to the Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lug), "lug" is "a broad-meaning word used of things that move slowly or with difficulty".

I've read all the [meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lug#Noun) listed in Wiktionary, and I can't understand what exactly "lug" means in "lug nut". I want to understand it in order to remember it better.

A picture I found online:

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lug is the threaded rod that the lug nut screws onto.

> A projection on an object by which it may be carried or fixed in place.
>   ‘mount the fitting directly to the lugs at each side of the box’ [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lug)

Comment: I see! Also "a part of something which sticks out, used as a handle or support" (Wiktionary). Interesting, thank you!

Comment: Also slang for ears.

Comment: In Middle English, a **lug(ge)** was a rod or stick. https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED26306